# Installing Kivy-designer

Tags: python, git, macos, kivy

I was wondering if there's an easy way to install kivy-designer. I am on Mac OS X and followed all the steps to install Kivy itself but when i tried to open application, it wasn't responding. However, when i wrote "kivy" in console, it launched the Python shell and I had no errors after executing command "import kivy":

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-03-31_1.txt



[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.0 (default, Dec 12 2015, 05:50:29) 

[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)]
```

Then i tried to install kivy-designer , using git, on the first try i got error that i needed to install cython, after i fixed it, by installing it with homebrew, new error appeared:

```
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider at all!

pygame - ImportError: No module named pygame

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib

    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pygame.py", line 12, in <module>

    import pygame




pil - ImportError: No module named PIL

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib

    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py", line 8, in <module>

    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw




[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

I tried to install pyGame using homebrew

Also tried this:

```
 git clone http://github.com/tito/osxrelocator
```

and even tried to reinstall Kivy with git:

```
git clone http://github.com/kivy/kivy
```

.

But i was getting same errors, without any updates.

Update:

Now i also tried:

`kivy main.py`
but i got this error:

```
   File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
     from designer.app import DesignerApp
   File "/Users/macbook/kivy-designer/kivy-designer/designer/app.py", line 8, in <module>
     from designer.add_file import AddFileDialog
   File "/Users/macbook/kivy-designer/kivy-designer/designer/add_file.py", line 5, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.filebrowser import FileBrowser
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 636, in _load_backward_compatible
 KeyError: 'kivy.garden.filebrowser'
```

Anyways, my question is:

**is there any way to install Kivy-designer app easily on Mac OS X?, or how can i fix these errors ?**

Thanks.

Comment: I followed the instructions to [install kivy with brew and pip](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html#using-pip). Then I followed the [instructions for kivy-designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer#installation) (first `pip` command), and it all works.

Comment: yeah i tried all those instructions right now, but it was still printing same error.

Comment: What does `pip show pygame` produce?

Comment: It doesn't print any errors or output, Just returns to command line.

Comment: That means it's not installed, at least not through pip. Try `pip install pygame` and see whether that works

Comment: It prints this:   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pygame
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/macbook/.pip/pip.log, However i have installed PyGame via homebrew.

Comment: My bad. Do you homebrew installed? Try `brew install pygame`. Obviously, pygame isn't found.

Comment: Well thats what i did, as i mentioned in post, The confusing thing is that, i don't get any errors after i execute that command, Most likely, it would show me error, But it just passed after i executed the command, so pygame is installed, but something does not work there.

Comment: does `python -c "import pygame;pygame.init()"` produce an error? And what does `echo $PYTHONPATH` produce?

Comment: first command produces: "ImportError: No module named pygame" and second does nothing, is it because of homebrew? or are there other ways to install pyGame?

Comment: ok now i have update, i tried 'pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame' and it opened app with PyGame icon, but closed it again.

Comment: no update about pythonpath, do i need to modify my .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found on how to solve this error, Thanks to zeeMonkeez for helping me:

The problem is that Homebrew is installing PyGame wrongly.

If your PyGame is not getting imported.

You need to try:

`pip install hg+bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`

and then upgrading pip:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

It should open main.py without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the osx .app package it's very important that you follow the explanations here https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html.

---

That means for Python modules (it this case to install the dependencies for kivy-designer):

```
kivy -m pip install <modulename>
```

In order to use binaries installed as mentioned above (like kivy-garden) you have to activate the virtual environment. In this example to install filebrowser.

```
source /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/bin/activate
garden install filebrowser
deactivate
```

---

Now I have observed that even by doing this last, filebrowser was being installed under `homedirectory/.kivy/garden/garden.filebrowser`. This was generating the error `KeyError: 'kivy.garden.filebrowser'` because it couldn't find it.

**The solution here is to copy the files from garden.filebrowser into** `/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/garden`

---

With this it should be all fine to start kivy-designer:

```
kivy -m designer
```

It took me a bit of time to find this. Hope this can help :)