# KeyError: 'kivy.garden.xpopup' when Installing Kivy Designer with Kivy3 and Python3 on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

**EDIT: As has been pointed out several times, this question looks like a duplicate of other questions about Kivy Designer.  As I show in the bolded section below however, and in my other comments, the solutions listed for those other questions have not worked for me.**

I am trying to install Kivy Designer on my mac and running into what seems to be a fairly common problem.  Following the [instructions on the installation page](http://kivy-designer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) (and, as suggested there, replacing 'python' with 'kivy'), when I try to run `kivy3 -m designer` I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Kivy3.app/Contents/Frameworks/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
 "__main__", mod_spec)
File "/Applications/Kivy3.app/Contents/Frameworks/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
 exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Users/*username*/kivy-designer/designer/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
 from designer.app import DesignerApp
File "/Users/*username*/kivy-designer/designer/app.py", line 14, in <module>
 from designer.components.dialogs.add_file import AddFileDialog
File "/Users/*username*/kivy-designer/designer/components/dialogs/add_file.py", line 5, in <module>
 from kivy.garden.xpopup.file import XFileOpen, XFolder
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 628, in _load_backward_compatible
KeyError: 'kivy.garden.xpopup'
```

I have spent a long time looking for a solution for this.  **The most commonly suggested solution is `garden install xpopup`.  When I run this, I get the message:**

```
Garden package already installed in /Users/*username*/.kivy/garden/garden.xpopup
Use --upgrade to upgrade.
```

**When I try running `kivy3 -m designer` again after this, I get the same KeyError.** I have tried various other solutions suggested here:

[Installing Kivy-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330659/installing-kivy-designer) (Attempted last solution listed, substituting 'xpopup' for 'filebrowser' where applicable)

[Installation of Kivy Designer on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556569/installation-of-kivy-designer-on-windows)
(Attempted second solution listed, using `kivy3 -m designer` instead of `python -m designer`)

but none of these have worked for me.

Does anyone have a different solution that has worked for them?

Thank you!

Comment: Please refer to the solution for [Kivy Designer Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495860/kivy-designer-is-not-working/46530129#46530129)

Comment: @ikolim Thank you for the prompt answer! Unfortunately neither reattempting the 'garden install' nor renaming 'xpopup_ru.mo' had an effect on the error I'm getting.  I still receive the KeyError shown in my question. Is this what is meant by the "Problem running Kivy Designer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it always crash."?

Comment: The crash is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Please try the following in a terminal window. (1) Display list of garden packages installed, `garden list` (2) Start Python Interactive Shell and import xpopup, `from kivy.garden.xpopup.file import XFileOpen, XFolder`.

Comment: @ikolim Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm not getting that message.  I get the following results from trying your suggestions in Terminal.

Comment: (1) xpopup
mapview
filebrowser

Comment: (2)  A long traceback with INFO messages which opens the Kivy UI

Comment: Install xpopup into the venv using `source /Applications/Kivy3.app/Contents/Resources/venv/bin/activate` and `garden install xpopup`

Comment: Again thank you for working through this with me!  I tried those commands and they both seemed to function (although I got the `Garden package already installed` message with the second one).  However when I try `kivy -m designer` I get the same traceback and KeyError from my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
garden install xpopup
```

it will do the trick.